# WordPress Sub Menu appearing behind content even with high z-index

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, z-index

I recently took over a WordPress site and the sub menu wasn't appearing at all. I fixed that with a li:hover style but now the sub menu appears behind the hero area. Played around with z-index to no luck.

Here's my two styles:

```
.main-header .main-navigation li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.main-header .main-navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

Site in question: http://brashind.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about adding overflow visible to the header, like so.

```
<header class="main-header" style="overflow: visible;">
```

I would also add background-color: white; to the sub-menu class if your going to do that, so the sub menu text is visible against the hero.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you have a `overflow: hidden;` for `.main-header` class, on this css file: `wp-content/themes/brashindustries/css/modules/header.css` - `line 28`. You can either remove that line (not recommended - as an update to theme file will remove your modifications), or override it like:

```
header.main-header {
    overflow: visible;
}
```